# possible cache miss with copying via pointers with addition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers

I wonder if some one could shed some light on whats going on here and a possible suggestion for a solution.

Using VS2010 ulimate c++ win7 x64.
Intel i5-3570 @ 3.4ghz, 8GB RAM.

I have a problem with a section of code running slowly which I was surprised to see as it's not really doing too much at all. At least I thought anyway. So using some old school timing techniques I narrowed the problem to a simple memory add and copy. Using the option to mix source and assembly for debugging output I get this...

```
byte* pback = (byte*)m_pBackbuffer;
000007FEF5661A5E  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbx+0CA800h]  
000007FEF5661A65  mov         ebp,eax  
byte* pout = (byte*)pSamplebuffer;
while(i--){
000007FEF5661A67  test        esi,esi  
000007FEF5661A69  je          AVNOnScreenRenderer::MergeBackbufferToOutputSample+70h (7FEF5661A80h)  
000007FEF5661A6B  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
    *pout++ = (*pback++ + *pout);
000007FEF5661A70  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [rdx]  
000007FEF5661A73  inc         rdi  
000007FEF5661A76  inc         rdx  
000007FEF5661A79  add         byte ptr [rdi-1],cl  
000007FEF5661A7C  dec         esi  
000007FEF5661A7E  jne         AVNOnScreenRenderer::MergeBackbufferToOutputSample+60h (7FEF5661A70h)
```

That little section of code is taking ~100ms to complete.

Where as removing the + pointer arithmetic reduces the code speed to 0 ms - using this code:

```
byte* pback = (byte*)m_pBackbuffer;
000007FEF5661A5E  mov         r8,qword ptr [rbx+0CA800h]  
000007FEF5661A65  mov         ebp,eax  
byte* pout = (byte*)pSamplebuffer;
while(i--){
000007FEF5661A67  test        edi,edi  
000007FEF5661A69  je          AVNOnScreenRenderer::MergeBackbufferToOutputSample+71h (7FEF5661A81h)  
000007FEF5661A6B  nop         dword ptr [rax+rax]  
    *pout++ = (*pback++);// + *pout);
000007FEF5661A70  movzx       ecx,byte ptr [r8]  
000007FEF5661A74  inc         rsi  
000007FEF5661A77  inc         r8  
000007FEF5661A7A  dec         edi  
000007FEF5661A7C  mov         byte ptr [rsi-1],cl  
000007FEF5661A7F  jne         AVNOnScreenRenderer::MergeBackbufferToOutputSample+60h (7FEF5661A70h)
```

I was expecting the very small time consumption in the first place but with the addition. At first I thought it was because I reading and writing to the same memory address, the *pout variable in the loop, but I've since created another buffer to write to and rearranged some parts to use other variables but the problem is very much still there. The problem is gone when I remove the +.

Could some brighter people help me solve this show stopper please.

ps an example of rearranging the code with another buffer is here...

```
byte* pback = (byte*)m_pBackbuffer;
byte* pout = (byte*)m_pOutbuffer;
while(i--){
    int b = *pback;
    int s = *pSamplebuffer;

    int o = b;//b + s;
    *pout = o;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing e.g. `*pout++ = o`? And why all the temporary variables?

Comment: yes, sorry that was a typo typing into the forum, the code above with the assembly output has the original source interleaved.

The temps? Just testing a hundred different things to get to find the problem which is the 100ms slow down when b + s in use in the code, regardless of incrementing the *pout variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the assembly printed above is equal to the code you execute at the end? A smart compiler should replace the second version with a simple `memcpy` thus speeding up the code essentially. This optimization is not possible for the first code snippet.

Depending on the size of your buffers, iterating through each element and applying an `add` operation can really consume some time.

Comment: Hiya, I've posted the output from setting a breakpoint and examining the disassembly in visual studio.The buffers are 1280 * 48 * 2 bytes. Its from some code to do a basic pixel blend with 2 yuyv images that I need to do in real time. A requirement is that the buffers come to my code and leave my code in cpu memory, changing that is out of my control ( Im thinking of gpu compute alternatives )

Comment: And you also use the debug version when you profile your code? Visual Studio will generate two different executable for debug and release mode. You should prefer the release version with optimizations enabled if you want to have meaningful measurements.

Comment: Yes, you're correct in that code posted is indeed the debug version. I have tried the release version with all optimisations switched on. It shaves a few millisecs off but nothing worth mentioning. I've not examined the assembly though as I thought the problem is still there regardless.
I didn't think the buffers were that large to have a performance impact of that magnitude - its a massive impact, do you agree?

Comment: I used the debug version to profile the code. It pointed me to a function that calls this one. So using the old tried and tested - take the millisecs before the loop and take the millisecs after the loop concludes that this little code is the bottleneck.

Comment: There must be something strange going on in the quantum world. I put this code into the production application, which does a damn sight more processing and it runs at 0ms as I was expecting.
Not impressed, but I'm glad in a strange way that it's ok.

Thankyou for taking the time to reply.

Comment: I also tried to reproduce the behavior but didn't make it. I could not see any difference in runtime between them both. All right if it works now.